# How to hide all that not in camera field of view

Tags: camera, shortcut

How to show only that part of the scene that can be seen from the camera and hide everything that does not fall into its field of vision.

I accidentally found this hotkey before, but I can not find it now.

Comment: By hiding, do you mean 'not rendering'?

Comment: No, hidding in 3d view window.

Comment: ***H*** hides an object in the 3D view, but what you're talking about only exists as an add-on.

Comment: I do not use third-party add-ons. This feature exist in standard blender instalation.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve? You're question is too brief, do you want to hide the objects so their affect doesn't appear in the render (reflections..etc)? Do you want to hide them in the viewport?

Comment: Never heard of that feature other than manually selecting the objects and hiding them, or possibly camera clipping settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. The hotkey is: **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>** (Clipping Border)

- Switch to camera view
- Press **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>**
- Select camera view area by cross selection tool
- Switch to 3d window
- Voila!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cant get this to work, do i need to do something else after Alt+B?

Answer (score 6):

You can also go to the camera setting, and click *Viewport Display*, and set the *Passepartout* to 1.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Feels better than having to do `Alt + B`