# View at the centre of an object, like a CT scan picture?

Tags: camera

Is it possible to view an object as if the camera starts from right at the centre of an object, like the image below, but not modifying the object like adding a loop-cut, select half of the object, and then hiding those parts?

[image]

Comment: This could be accomplished by using Solidify and a Boolean modifier.

Comment: Use Alt+B for this. (note that you might want to set the view to orthographic perspective so that the visible part is box-shaped in 3d rather than trapezoidal)
See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75780/how-to-hide-all-that-not-in-camera-field-of-view/75832?r=SearchResults#75832

Comment: A shader controlling the transparency would also be an option, as described in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164425/74827).

Comment: @RobertRoth I tried Alt+B, and it seemed to get the result I wanted and it was simple, so I choose that as the answer.